# CSS Function in mixin - grayscale

Tags: css, sass, grayscale

I'm trying to create a mixin for grayscaling an html element.

In CSS way, it should be :

```
filter: grayscale(50%);
```

My mixin :

```
@mixin grayscale_element($value) {
    -webkit-filter: grayscale($value);
    -moz-filter: grayscale($value);
    filter: grayscale($value);
}
```

My error :

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'SassScriptFunctionException' with message 'SassNumber must be a SassColour
Source: -webkit-filter: grayscale($value)'
```

Problem is, in sass grayscale is already a function, and paramter should be a color.

[Module: Sass::Script::Functions - Sass Documentation](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html#grayscale-instance_method)

How can I use these filter in a mixin ?

Note: I'm using phpsass.

Comment: I am not sure what your problem is exactly. If you need string interpolation / escaping the function name and parsing it to CSS - then I think @MartinTurjak's answer beneath is the solution.

Answer (score 14):

If you just want to avoid the `grayscale` function being evaluated as a Sass function use string interpolation. Something like this:

```
filter: #{"grayscale(#{$value})"};
```

if `$value` is set to 50% the CSS output will be:

```
filter: grayscale(50%);
```

#### [Demo](http://sassmeister.com/gist/7136082)

Answer (score 0):

The code works fine for me as long as I included the mixin like:

```
@include grayscale_element(100%);
```

When a string was passed to the mixin, it failed as you mentioned.

```
$val: 100%;
@include grayscale_element(#{$val});
```

Type should be estimated.

Comment: Ok thanks for your answer, actually I use PHPSass, I guess that's the problem and not really SASS so.